# Highcharts update series type dataloss

Tags: updates, highcharts, series, data-loss

I'm trying to update series types in **Highchart** but there is a data loss in it.

Here is my snippet:

```
h = Highcharts.charts[0]
h.series[0].options.type
-> "candlestick"
h.series[0].options.data[0]
-> [1386543600000, 111.69, 111.79, 109, 109.39]

h.series[0].update({type: "spline"})
h.series[0].options.data[0]
-> Object {x: 1386543600000, y: 111.69}
```

jsfiddle, which show the dataloss with Highstock/StockChart: http://jsfiddle.net/fqd1bshm/1/

**Update 1**

If I use the navigator with Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/9mby1xqn/1/
the same problem occurs.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use any wrappers? Can you replicate your example as live demo ?

Comment: Yes, create a fiddle.  I started one here: http://jsfiddle.net/0ns95amo/ but can't replicate your results.  I don't lose data, I can toggle from spline to candlestick.

Comment: Thanks for your fast replies. 
I think its a stockchart problem. http://jsfiddle.net/fqd1bshm/1/

Comment: It is related with the fact, that when you update to spline, then y value is replaced by lowa value, but other are cut. So when you back, you have lost low/high/open/close.

Comment: @SebastianBochan: I think i figured that out, already. Any Solutions for that?

Comment: due to @Mark, i went back to normal Highcharts without using Highstock and enabled the navigator. Then there was the dataloss again.

Comment: @JakubWerner, glad you found a solution.  Please *answer* your own question and then when the system allows, accept it (green checkmark).  This will help others with the same problem find the solution in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. It was the navigator that "updates" the data. If you want it to stop doing that, you have to set the adaptToUpdatedData value in the Highcharts configuration.

Should then look like this:

```
navigator: {
  enabled: true,
  adaptToUpdatedData: false
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9mby1xqn/3/